# A PHP Error was encountered - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I encountered the following error. How do fix I

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at application\libraries\template.php:1)
Filename: libraries/Session.php
Line Number: 672
```

but this page doesn't exist session process

Comment: You should also post relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you 're printing out (echo, var_dump etc) something before session initialization. Post some code to help

Comment: First of all, I fixed ouerror. Reason of error is UTF-8 (without BOM). You should write your codes without BOM.